# Google Channel API /_ah/channel/connected/ not called while /_ah/channel/disconnected/ is

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

Using Google Channel API I find that 
/_ah/channel/disconnected/ is always called promptly while
/_ah/channel/connected/ is not.  Many times I never get a connect call and then get a disconnect call for a channel which the server has not been notified about!

(I saw some people had the opposite problem that disconnect is delayed)

Comment: This has happened to me, but only in the SDK, not on Google's server. The SDK implementation is different, it uses polling instead of Comet.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? This is happening to me regularly even on Google's server. Moreover, when /_ah/channel/connected is not called the channel is unusable. I have filed a bug report. Please star it if this bug is affecting you: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8334

Comment: I'm having that same issue! has anyone resolved it? that link to the bug is broken. thanks.

Comment: Since that link is broken, I reopened a ticket to this issue here:  https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11048.  Hope this helps!